# What's up with the Sheffer stroke axiom?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, formal-proofs, formal-systems

While reading some old paper on the foundations of set theory, I came across a symbol $\mid$ that I eventually determined was the [Sheffer stroke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheffer_stroke), which is a fancy word for NAND.

Wikipedia, and also the paper, has only this to say about working with the Sheffer stroke:

> All [well-formed formulas] of the form $$((U \mid (V \mid W)) \mid ((Y \mid (Y \mid Y)) \mid ((X \mid V) \mid ((U \mid X) \mid (U \mid X)))))$$ are axioms. Instances of $$(U \mid (V \mid W)),\, U \vdash W$$ are inference rules.

This is a remarkable achievement in concise formulation: it leaves out everything that I understand about axiomatic proofs. My question could be summarized as "what the heck?" but for the sake of people trying to answer it, I'll try to be a little bit more precise.

How do you actually work with the *thing* above? What do the parts of a proof in language I understand become when you use the Sheffer stroke instead? If the only axiom is the disaster above, how do you ever conclude anything that makes sense?

I'm guessing that an example of a proof of *something, anything* using this formal system, with an explanation, would answer my question and address my confusion.

Comment: A similar issue, the definition of number 1 by Bourbaki: https://mathoverflow.net/q/357498

Comment: Not clear your concern... “Common” proof systems for propositional calculus use more “usual” basic sets of connectives and axioms exactly for human readibility Having said that, the discovery that a single connective and a single axiom (plus a rule of inference) is enough were e remarkable discovery. We can use it to implement “mechanical” proof systems, were the machine has no readibility concern. And the NAND gate is used.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I'm not even clear on how to do the basic things in this system, never mind readability. For example, the $((Y \mid (Y \mid Y))$ bit inside the axiom should "evaluate to TRUE" in terms of NAND, but I don't know how you can prove that when all you have is this axiom. And that seems like a basic step for using the axiom to do anything else!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out this is just one Sheffer stroke axiom.  There's an old paper by Lukasiewicz, which got entitled *Generalizing Deduction* if I recall correctly, where he finds that Nicod's axiom, which could get translated to DDpDqrDDtDttDDsqDDpsDps in Polish notation has a substitution instance which is also a single axiom: DDpDqrDDsDssDDsqDDpsDps.  Wajsberg found another single axiom in 1931 DDpDqrDDDsrDDpqDDpsDpDpq, and Lukasiewicz in 1931 DDpDqrDDpDrpDDsqDDpsDps.  Over [60 more 23-letter single](https://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/AR/award-2001/fitelson.pdf) axioms in the Sheffer stroke got found by Ernst, Fitelson, and Harris.  There also exist single axioms for calculi with more than one connective, and a theorem which ensures the existence of single axioms for non-classical propositional calculi which have certain theorems which hold.

```
How do you actually work with the thing above?
```

The key observation consists in that Nicod's axiom has the same form as *all* of the assumptions in the argument "if DpDqr, and p, then r", where the second 'p' does not differ at all from the 'p' in 'DpDqr'.  Or, if translated to infix, Nicod's axiom has form '(U|(V|W))', and has form 'U' also simultaneously.

More generally, all single axioms which operate under a single rule of inference work similarly, since if they didn't, the rule of inference couldn't get used to infer anything, since every formula before using a rule of inference initially has to get obtained from a substitution of the axiom.

So, the first step for a formal proof involving Nicod's axiom involves making two substitution instances of that axiom, one of the form 'DpDqr', the other of the form 'p', where 'p' has the same form as in 'DpDqr', and then infer 'r'.  The easiest way to do this might be to use condensed (Sheffer stroke) detachment, where the axiom sort of suggests a substitution all by itself.  Informally, that's a way of doing "as little" substitution as possible in the formulas to infer something, and thus what gets inferred is at least as general as anything else derivable in one detachment.  To do condensed detachment, first make sure that the formulas have no variables in common.  For Nicod's axiom:

1. DDpDqrDDtDttDDsqDDpsDps
2. DDaDbcDDdDddDDebDDaeDae

will do.  The following diagram, which recasts 1. and 2. with some spacing, I think helps:

```
D D p     D q     r           DDtDttDDsqDDpsDps
    |       |     |
    -----   ----- -----------
  D DaDbc D DdDdd DDebDDaeDae
```

Now, and this case is fairly simple for condensed detachment, substitute p with DaDbc, q with DdDdd, and r with DDebDDaeDae and we get:

3. DDDaDbcDDdDddDDebDDaeDaeDDtDttDDsDdDddDDDaDbcsDDaDbcs

So, we have the required forms to use the rule of inference, since 3. has the form 'DxDyz', with 2. as the 'x', having the same for as in 3.

Or in other words, since the first part of 3. matches that of 2. we can now infer:

4. DDsDdDddDDDaDbcsDDaDbcs

I'm not clear about your second question.

```
If the only axiom is the disaster above, how do you ever conclude anything that makes sense?
```

If this is taken to mean something that we might find more comprehensible to understand in natural language, we might note that just by applying a definition DpDpp turns into Cpp ("(p$\rightarrow$p)").  Uniform substitution in the axiom, and/or proven (object-language) theorems, using the rule of inference can prove formulas like that.

The following is a first-order proof via William McCune's Prover9 which has clues as to how to construct a propositional calculus proof of DxDxx:

```
1 P(D(x,D(x,x))) # label(non_clause) # label(goal).  [goal].
2 -P(D(x,D(y,z))) | -P(x) | P(z).  [assumption].
3 P(D(D(x,D(y,z)),D(D(u,D(u,u)),D(D(w,y),D(D(x,w),D(x,w)))))).  [assumption].
4 -P(D(c1,D(c1,c1))).  [deny(1)].
5 P(D(D(x,D(y,D(y,y))),D(D(D(z,D(u,w)),x),D(D(z,D(u,w)),x)))).  [hyper(2,a,3,a,b,3,a)].
6 P(D(D(x,D(D(y,D(z,u)),w)),D(D(D(w,D(v5,D(v5,v5))),x),D(D(w,D(v5,D(v5,v5))),x)))).  [hyper(2,a,3,a,b,5,a)].
10 P(D(D(D(D(x,y),D(D(z,x),D(z,x))),D(u,D(u,u))),D(z,D(y,w)))).  [hyper(2,a,6,a,b,3,a)].
12 P(D(D(x,D(y,z)),D(D(D(u,w),D(D(w,u),D(w,u))),D(v5,D(v5,v5))))).  [hyper(2,a,5,a,b,10,a)].
14 P(D(x,D(x,x))).  [hyper(2,a,12,a,b,12,a)].
```

Comment: Your answer resolves a little of my confusion. I guess what I meant by "how do we ever conclude anything that makes sense?" is that anything we infer from this axiom seems doomed to be at least as long and complicated. If we want to prove a simple statement (I'm still attached to `DaDaa` as a simple statement that ought to be provable) then some sort of dramatic cancellation has to happen at some point, and I don't see how.

Comment: Your answer, by way of saying "Nicod's axiom", also pointed me to [this paper](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/A_Reduction_in_the_number_of_the_Primitive_Propositions_of_Logic), which I think helps me understand what's going on, though I still have to read it carefully.

Comment: @MishaLavrov If I recall correctly, there was an error in Nicod's paper which got corrected later on in some publication.  I don't think the error affected the readability of that paper.

Comment: @MishaLavrov It's usually permissible to also use derived theorems.  I think that makes it easier to get shorter formulas than the Nicod axiom does.  I've updated the answer with basically a guide on how DaDaa could get proved.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Dramatic cancellations are possible because the conclusion $W$ of the rule of inference can sometimes be much smaller than either premise.  The same thing happens in more traditional proof systems with the rule of modus ponens. The proof of $A\to A$ from substitution instances of $A\to(B\to A)$ and $((A\to(B\to C))\to((A\to B)\to(A\to C))$ involves first going to a somewhat bigger formula and then using modus ponens to shrink it.

Comment: @AndreasBlass I've thought a little more a bit about this, and though modus ponens definitely does produce a shorter formula than either of the two premises, the amount of increase in length of formulas from substitution (or instatiation) often, and perhaps always?, is greater than the decrease in length from the use of modus ponens.  If we consider the one-variable proof of (A→A) that I think you referred to, all substitution happens up front though, and the (A→A) isn't the consequent of any axiom, it's the consequent of a consequent of an axiom.

Comment: Also, if we have a form of (A→(B→A)) as the major premise (the premise of the form ($\alpha$$\rightarrow$$\beta$)), then we'll infer something of the form (B→A), which is necessarily longer than any minor premise of the form A.  If we have a form of ((A→(B→C))→((A→B)→(A→C)) as the major premise, we'll infer something of the form ((A→B)→(A→C)) which is longer than any minor premise of the form (A→(B→C)).  But, if we have a major premise of the form ((A→B)→(A→C)), we'll infer (A→C), which can be shorter than the minor premise of the form (A→B),.

Answer (score 6):

[Doug Spoonwood's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3816026) was very helpful, as was [Jean Nicod's paper](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/A_Reduction_in_the_number_of_the_Primitive_Propositions_of_Logic) introducing the Sheffer stroke axiom, but I'm going to accept the former because Nicod doesn't appear interested in StackExchange karma.

I'm going to post my own answer describing what I learned about working with the Sheffer stroke and with this axiom in particular. My personal goal was to prove $Y \mid (Y\mid Y)$, since it seemed like a very simple fact that should be true; below, I prove that, and a few other things, in potentially human-readable form.

### How I learned to stop worrying and love the Sheffer stroke

Some nicer notation, partly borrowed from Nicod:

- $x \mid y/z$ as shorthand for $x \mid (y \mid z)$; in general, $/$ is a version of $\mid$ that is higher in order of operations, to avoid parentheses.
- $\overline{x}$ as shorthand for $x \mid x$; this can be read as (and is equivalent to, outside the system) "not $x$". Note that from $x$ and $x \mid \overline y$, we can infer $y$.
- $\pi_x$ as shorthand for $x \mid \overline x = x \mid x/x$. This should be true for all $x$.
- $[x,y]$ as shorthand for $x/y \mid \overline{y/x}$. This should be true for all $x,y$; from $[x,y]$ and $x\mid y$, we can "swap $x$ and $y$" and infer $y \mid x$.
- $[x,y,z]$ as shorthand for $(x\mid y/z) \mid \overline{z/y \mid x}$. This should be true for all $x,y,z$; from $[x,y,z]$ and $x \mid y/z$, we can "reflect $x,y,z$" and infer $z/y \mid x$.

(Nicod uses $\pi$ for a specific $\pi_t$; $[x,y]$ and $[x,y,z]$ are all mine, inspired by commutator brackets in a completely different area of math.)

In this answer, I'll prove $\pi_x$, $[x,y]$, and $[x,y,z]$ for all $x$,$y$, and $z$.

**Lemma 1.** $[x, \pi_y]$ for all $x,y$.

**Proof.** The single axiom we've got can be written as
$$
    (u \mid v/w) \mid \pi_y / ( x/v \mid \overline{u/x}).
$$
In particular, if we set $u=v$ in the axiom, we have
$$
    (u \mid u/w) \mid \pi_y / [x,u].
$$
If we can prove anything of the form $u \mid u/w$, we can deduce $[x,u]$. In particular, setting $u=v=w=x=y$ in the axiom gives us $\pi_y \mid \pi_y / [y,y]$, which has that form; therefore, we have $[x, \pi_y]$ for all $x$ and $y$.

**Lemma 2.** $[x,\pi_y,z]$ for all $x,y,z$.

**Proof.** Suppose we want to try to infer $[x,y,z] = (x\mid y/z) \mid \overline{z/y \mid x}$ from the axiom. In general, things we infer from the axiom have the form $x/v \mid \overline{u/x}$, which matches $[x,y,z]$ if we have $u = z\mid y$ and $v = y\mid z$. Setting $w = y \mid z$ in the axiom to simplify things, we get
$$
    ((z\mid y) \mid (y \mid z)/(y \mid z)) \mid \pi_y / ((x\mid y/z) \mid \overline{z/y \mid x})
$$
which simplifies to
$$
    [z,y] \mid \pi_y / [x,y,z]
$$
so if we prove $[z,y]$, we can infer $[x,y,z]$. In particular, by Lemma 1, we can infer $[x, \pi_y, z]$ for all $x,y,z$.

**Theorem.** $\pi_y$, $[x,y]$, and $[x,y,z]$ for all $x,y,z$.

**Proof.** Setting $u=v=w$ in the axiom gives us $\pi_u \mid \pi_y / [x,u]$ which we now "reflect" by Lemma 2 into $[x,u] / \pi_y \mid \pi_u$ and "swap" by Lemma 1 into $\pi_u \mid [x,u] / \pi_y$. So if we prove $\pi_u$ for *any* $u$, we can use this to infer $\pi_y$ for *all* $y$.

But we've already proven $[\pi_y, \pi_y]$ (as a special case of Lemma 1) which can be rewritten as
$$
   [\pi_y, \pi_y] = \pi_y / \pi_y \mid \overline{\pi_y / \pi_y} = \pi_{\pi_y \mid \pi_y}.
$$
From $\pi_{\pi_y \mid \pi_y} \mid [x,\pi_y \mid \pi_y] / \pi_y$ and $\pi_{\pi_y \mid \pi_y}$, we infer $\pi_y$ (for all $y$).

Setting $u=v=w=y$ in our earlier formula $(u \mid u/w) \mid \pi_y / [x,u]$ gives us $\pi_y \mid \pi_y / [x,y]$, and now that we know $\pi_y$, we infer $[x,y]$ (for all $x,y$).

Now, from the formula $[z,y] \mid \pi_y / [x,y,z]$, we infer $[x,y,z]$ (for all $x,y,z$).